# Insert GNOME panel text to rightmost index

Tags: gnome, suspend, gnome-shell-extension, extension

I am the author of the extension [Mock Universal Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4111/mock-universal-menu/), and am working on the next update.  The problem is, I want to insert my text to the rightmost index of the left box.  I want to do this because as of now, after coming out from suspend, my extension goes to the left of the app menu (ex, `Firefox`, or `Extensions`), and after the activities button.  So, my question is: Would it be possible to stop this behavior, and if not, how do I align it to the right of the left box.

## My Code

```js
'use strict';

const { St, Clutter } = imports.gi;

const Main = imports.ui.main;

let _myText;

class Extension {

    enable() {
    const _myText = new St.Label({ text: '  File        Edit        View        Go        Window        Help', 
    y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER, 
    style_class: 'panel-button', 
    track_hover: false, 
    reactive: false, 
    style_class: 'panel-button my-class'});
    Main.panel._leftBox.insert_child_at_index(_myText, 10)
    }

    disable() {
    _myText.destroy();
    }
}

function init() {
    return new Extension();
}
```

I am on Ubuntu 21.04 with GNOME 40.4 installed.

Comment: Hi, Change your disable() function as below and see     `disable() {
    Main.panel._leftBox.remove_child(_myText);
    }`

Comment: I would replace my current disable() function with this, correct?

Comment: it has no effect, after suspend, it is still to the left of the application button.  Maybe if there was an alignment option to align first or last in relation to the left box?

Comment: Oops, I should've mentioned, I'm on Ubuntu 21.04.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: When I disable, I get an error: `Expected an object of type ClutterActor for argument 'child' but got type undefined`.

Comment: yes, I understand that the one on the extensions website is fully functional.  The error occurs when you wake from suspend.  The extension is then to the left of the application menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you have provided, it seems the disable function like below will do what you are looking for

```
disable() { 
Main.panel._leftBox.remove_child(_myText);
}
```

also remove the text "const" from your enable code 2nd line

```
enable() {
    const _myText = new St.Label({ text: '  File        Edit        View .....
```

Comment: I also had to disable `const` before `_myText`

Comment: yes, thats correct.